# R - Change row values based on the contents of neighbouring rows

Tags: r, neighbours

I have a series of numbers in two columns, with the titles `"a"` and `"b"`.

I want to get `R` to change the values in column `"b"` if the difference between a value in column "`a"` is greater than 10 from its neighboring cells.

For example:

```
a   |   b
-----------    
1   |   1
2   |   1
3   |   1
4   |   1
21  |   1
22  |   1
23  |   1
24  |   1
... |   ...
```

Then I would like R to change the values in column "b" to

```
a   |   b
-----------    
1   |   1
2   |   1
3   |   1
4   |   0
21  |   0
22  |   1
23  |   1
24  |   1
... |   ...
```

Because the values 4 and 21 in the a-column are greater than 10 from each other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:4, 21:24), b = 1)

# check whether differences are greater than 10 
diffs <- diff(df$a) > 10

# create `b`
df$b <- as.integer(!(c(FALSE, diffs) | c(diffs, FALSE)))
```

The result:

```
   a b
1  1 1
2  2 1
3  3 1
4  4 0
5 21 0
6 22 1
7 23 1
8 24 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:4, 21:24), b = 1L)
local({
 w10 <- with(df, which(diff(a) > 10)))
 df$b[c(w10, w10+1)] <<- 0L
})
```